# How can I get the worst reputation possible?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

As we all know our choices have some affect in Skyrim. Are there any quests in Skyrim that have choices that can impair or cripple the game? I'm looking for all possible ways to make Skyrim a bad land and make all quest related NPC characters look down upon me.

Are there any quests that give a choice that affect other things in Skyrim, and what are the major choices?

Comment: Kill civilians and guards -> Repeat. If you don't want to be the last person in the game then possibly keep doing repeatable dark brotherhood quests? (Haven't done any research to confirm so not posting this as an answer)

Comment: This seems overly broad and relatively unanswerable - I can think of tons of ways to make the game unplayable (deleting files from the game directory seems the easiest route).  Can you focus the question a bit better?  What's your goal, exactly?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The following conditions will greatly impact on NPCs stance towards you.

### [Vampirism](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Vampirism)

> **Vampires** are hated and feared by the general population and will be attacked on sight if their true nature is discovered.
>
> - Stage three vampirism: **most NPCs will not interact with you** if you initiate the conversation.
> - Stage four vampirism: **nearly all NPCs become hostile and will attack on sight**, including spouses and followers.

### [Lycanthropy - Beast Form](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Werewolves#Beast_Form)

> **Almost all NPCs will become hostile** (exceptions include other werewolves, Maiq The Liar, Melka, members of the Dark Brotherhood,
> Paarthurnax, followers, housecarls, and members of the Thieves Guild
> [verification needed], but not your spouse, unless your spouse is one
> of these)

**Note:** You have to choose to be either a vampire or a werewolf.

### [High Bounty](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Bounty)

Comitting any crime causes the Hold guards to attack you.

**Bounty Collector**

> If your bounty is above 1000 gold, you may be met by a Bounty
> Collector.

### [Sacred Chickens](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Chicken)

> There are consequences for killing a chicken. Even though the bounty
> is as low as 45, the townsfolk will kill the violator if they get the
> chance.

Sheathing the weapon has no effect on Hold Guards. You better run.

[image: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zFIZfuDLEy8]
[**Source**](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zFIZfuDLEy8)

For some reason chickens are for Skyrim what cows are for indians. Not delicious but sacred.